# Multiple conditions in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm copying some data onto another worksheet but need to input multiple conditions in my `if` function - within my workbook, column `H` has chocolate, strawberry, vanilla - I just want chocolate and strawberry to be shifted to the next sheet. So far I have,

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value = "chocolate"
```

How do I tell VBA to move the whole row if column `H` has chocolate or strawberry? I tried -

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value = "chocolate" Then
ElseIf If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value = "strawberry"
```

But it ended up just keeping only the strawberry rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for your vba If statement.

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value = "chocolate" Or Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value = "Strawberry" Then
...
Your code
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! If my H column had values such as "chocolate ice cream" is there a way I could get the code to capture "chocolate ice cream" instead of only "chocolate" without having to write a different Or statement for it?

Comment: Yes, try `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value  Like "chocolate*"`. This is case sensitive but you can put the values in the Lower() function to avoid it. The * makes the comparison wildcard for 0 or more characters.